# Collecting data from map to list using Java 8

Tags: java-8

Please help me with the Java 8 map - filter - sort - collect code.

**Info.java**

```
public class Info {
private final String name;
private final String desc;
private String version = null;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if (that == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (that instanceof Info) {
        Info other = (Info) that;

        return Objects.equals(this.name, other.name) &&
                Objects.equals(this.desc, other.desc) &&
                Objects.equals(this.version, other.version);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean equalsWithoutVersion(Object that) {
    if (that == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (that instanceof Info) {
        Info other = (Info) that;

        return Objects.equals(this.name, other.name) &&
                Objects.equals(this.desc, other.desc);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 13;
    hash = (hash * 7) + name.hashCode();
    hash = (hash * 7) + desc.hashCode();

    if (version != null)
        hash = (hash * 7) + version.hashCode();

    return hash;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String versionString = version == null ? "latest" : version;
    return String.format("Name: %s  Desc: %s  Key Type: %s Version: %s", this.name, this.desc, this.keyType.name(), versionString);
}
}
```

**Value.java**

```
public class Value implements Comparable<Value> {
private String data;
private String version;

public Value(String version, String data) {
    this.version = version;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Value o) {
    return (Integer.parseInt(this.version) > Integer.parseInt(o.version)) ? -1
            : (Integer.parseInt(this.version) < Integer.parseInt(o.version)) ? 1
            : 0;
}
}
```

**Cache.java**

```
public class Cache {
    private final Map<Info, Value> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    ...
    private Value getlatestVersionFromCache(Info info) {
    List<Value> values = dataMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getKey().equalsWithoutVersion(info))
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(x::getValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return values.isEmpty() ? null : values.get(0);
}
}
```

The goal is to obtain the latest version of a record from the map. So first I am filtering entries from the map by comparing fields of `Info` without version. Then I am sorting the map by value based on version.  Then I am collecting the values to a list. Then I can get the first element to get the latest version.

But I am getting the following compilation error on the filter statement:

```
Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected
```

Comment: what is `Key`  structure in `private Key getlatestVersionFromCache(){...}`?

Comment: why do you get `version` as _String_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I doubt about your solution. I think you can do it in simple way. so first change `version` type to `Integer` in `Value` class(*in compareTo() method you converted it to Integer*). and also change method signature to `Optional<Value>` in `getlatestVersionFromCache()` method.

also I think you don't need to sort `dataMap`.

```
private Optional<Value> getlatestVersionFromCache(Info info) {
     Map<Value,Integer> result = dataMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getKey().equalsWithoutVersion(info))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, entry -> entry.getValue().getVersion(), Integer::min));

   Optional<Value> latestValue = result.keySet()
           .stream()
           .min(Comparator.comparingInt(key -> key.getVersion()));

     return latestValue;
}
```

---

Better solution is something like this:

```
dataMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getKey().equalsWithoutVersion(info))
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().getVersion()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: what does this line do? `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, entry -> entry.getValue().getVersion(), Integer::min))`

Comment: @cppcoder it compute min value object based on version property. but I think this is more efficient. `Optional<Map.Entry<Info, Value>> latestValue = dataMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(p -> p.getKey().equalsWithoutVersion(info))
               .min(Comparator.comparingInt(entry->entry.getValue().getVersion()));` and `latestValue.get().getValue();`

Answer (score 1):

You have several omissions and errors in the code you posted, but the `filter` statement was actually fine.

The following passes compilation:

```
List<Value> values = dataMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getKey().equalsWithoutVersion(info))
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // was .map(x::getValue)) - x is not defined anywhere, so
                                  // I assumed you meant Map.Entry::getValue
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And the problem was the extra paranthesis here: `.map(x::getValue))`

Comment: `stream()` was present in my code, though I missed to put in the question initially though. Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Info {

    public static final BiPredicate<Info, Info> IS_EQUAL_IGNORE_VERSION =
            (one, two) -> one.getName().equals(two.getName()) && one.getDesc().equals(two.getDesc());

    private final String name;
    private final String desc;
    private String version;
}


private final Map<Info, Value> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

public Value getlatestVersionFromCache(Info info) {
    Value value = null;

    for (Map.Entry<Info, Value> entry : dataMap.entrySet())
        if (Info.IS_EQUAL_IGNORE_VERSION.test(entry.getKey(), info))
            if (value == null || Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().getVersion()) > Integer.parseInt(value.getVersion()))
                value = entry.getValue();

    return value;
}
```

Notes:

1. I think that use a comparator to check that two objects are queal is not correct. You can use e.g. `Predicate`. And define it as a static method in the target class.
2. Pay attention on `version`. It seems that it should be an integer instead of String.
3. In your approach, compare two string is not correct, because it is used instead of `equals` method.
4. I think that using `Java8` streams only because this is a stream is alow not correct.